# Why can fixed types be assigned to a type with an index signature, but interfaces can't?

Tags: typescript

See this example:

```
interface JsonObject {
    [key: string]: JsonValue
}
type JsonValue = JsonObject | JsonValue[] | boolean | number | string | null;
export type Json = JsonObject | JsonValue;

//---------------------------------------------------------------

interface A {
    b: string
}
type B = {
    b: string
};

const AValue: A = {
    b: "foo"
};
const BValue: B = {
    b: "foo"
};

function serialize(val: Json) {
    JSON.stringify(val);
}

serialize(AValue); //TS2345 error
serialize(BValue); //No error

// Both of these generate an error
AValue["x"] = 4;
BValue["x"] = 4;
```

Comment: it is clear why AValue cannot be given to the func - the function could be doing `val["foo"]` which the JsonObject allows, but `A` does not.
Though the same should apply to `B` as well...

Comment: Might I suggest a more concise reproduction:

```
interface A {
    b: string
}
type B = {
    b: string;
};

const val = {
    b: "foo"
};

val as A as Record<string, string>;
val as B as Record<string, string>;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QIwC5kBnMKUAcywF8swBPABxQCFkBeTHPI08qgG5awrAgD2IMsgBucADadueAsQBEMceLUisWOYrgk0yI8gBKECVAAmAHjIUQlADT8nlAHzCDp4+zNLa3tHKjdQ528sIA

Comment: @Knaģis: No, the way TS works is that the shape of the passed type fits the shape of the parameter type. The shape of `B` "fits" the shape of `Json`, so it can be assigned to it. Interfaces, on the other hand, are weird beasts...

Comment: One thing that may factor into the OP's problem is that interfaces can be extended very differently to regular object types.